# Find object in array and update it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of objects:

```
[
   { c: 'AAPL', price: 500 },
   { c: 'GGOG', price: 100 }
]
```

I want to update GOOG price, extending an object with new quote object.

How do I find indexOf GOOG object in array without looping? 
Is that possible by native functions of js or jquery?

Comment: Why do you hate loops? You _have to_ use a loop.

Comment: @undefined, I ask quoestions to find out not known function wich can make life easier. 

I bet you use native .filter function instead of looping all the time. And I bet you use native .indexOf function instead of looping. 

Answer "there is no shorthand or native function for that" is better then teaching.

Comment: Even the `filter` and `$.grep` are considered a loop, the callback is executed once for each array's elements. If you program heavily uses array of objects, you can consider using Underscore library which provides many utility functions.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `$.grep` to find an object in an array by a known value:

```
var google = $.grep(arr, function(item){ return item.c == 'GOOG'; });
google[0].price = 200;
```

Alternatively, if you would like to update the object within the original array, you would need to use a loop. Something like this:

```
function findStock(name) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i].c == name) return arr[i];
    }
}

function updateStock(name, price) {
    var stock = findStock(name);
    if (stock) stock.price = price;
}

updateStock('GOOG', 750);
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hvg3Larg/)

Comment: Nice one. Didn't even know `.grep()`.

Comment: It should be noted that `$.grep` returns an array, so the second line should be `google[0].price`.

Comment: I need to change(extend) object IN original array.
Grep seems to create NEW array which is no use for me.

Comment: Yep, i know ho to do it with loop. But i wonder if there is shorter (native) way.

Comment: @ProstoTrader I'm afraid not.

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to use native JS as well.

```
var obj=[
{ c: 'AAPL', price: 500 },
{ c: 'GGOG', price: 100 }
];

findIndexOf(obj, 'GGOG', 'c');
function findIndexOf(inObj, searchStr, objAttribute){
    for(var i in inObj){
        if(inObj[i][objAttribute]==searchStr)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `Array.map` like this:

```js
var upd='GOOG',p=250,u=false;

array.map(function(){
    if(!u&&this.c==upd)
    {
         this.price=p;
         u=true;
    }
});
```